# Перезапись xml файла на c#

Tags: c#, xml

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста как изменить один из элементов xml файла и перезаписать, вот код

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("D:\\items.xml");
        foreach (XElement phoneElement in xdoc.Element("request").Elements("auth"))
        {
            XAttribute nameAttribute = phoneElement.Attribute("count");


            if (nameAttribute != null)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Смартфон: {0}", nameAttribute.Value);
                Int32 kkk = Convert.ToInt32(nameAttribute.Value);
                kkk++;

                Console.WriteLine("Смартфон: {0}", kkk);


            }
             Console.WriteLine();
             xdoc.Save("D:\\items22.xml");
           }
```

элемент изменяется но не перезаписывается, я только начинаю программировать заранее извиняюсь за ошибки...

Comment: Вы изменяете не значение элемента, а только значение kkk. После изменения kkk нужно сохранить его nameAttribute.SetValue(kkk);

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После изменения kkk нужно было сохранить его nameAttribute.SetValue(kkk).